# Why does java socket report an error if it doesn't read all the data

Tags: java, sockets, http

I am learning to write a simple HTTP server recently, because the function is very simple, as long as the user access will respond to a picture. So, I decided not to read the user's request data (because I didn't need it), but when I used my browser to access localhost: 10000, there was a problem -- the picture couldn't be displayed completely and I couldn't download it. However, when I read the user's request, it will work normally. If I only read part of the request data, the program will not work properly.

Here is my simplified code.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(10000)) {
            while (true) {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("user connecting。。。");

                OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
//              InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
//              StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder(80);
//              while (true) {
//                  int c = in.read();
//                  if (c == '\r' || c == '\n' || c == -1) break;
//                  request.append((char)c);
//              }
                File file = new File("D:/DragonFile/target/attitude.jpg");
                long length = file.length();
                byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

                String header = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n" 
                        + "Server: crazy\r\n"
                        + "ContentType-length: " + length + "\r\n"
                        + "Content-Type: " + "image/jpg" + "; charset=" + "UTF-8" + "\r\n\r\n";

                out.write(header.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));  //response header
                out.write(data);       //response body
                out.flush();        // flush the stream
                client.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run this code, and use the browser to access localhost: 10000, and a picture will be displayed, but this program has a bug.

[image]

When I cancel the comment part above, the code can run normally, and it is normal to access the pictures.

Here is a picture of normal access.
[image]

This is my first question, please help me and tell me why. I am interesting about it.

Comment: Because you are violating the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a socket as two straws (one in one direction and the other in the other). If you put something in the straw and the other side doesn't take it out, you will notice and will not be able to put anything more into it.

HTTP is defined as "The client puts their request in, the server reads it and then puts a response in the other straw".

By not taking everything from the straw, you broke the contract and the browser doesn't like that.

Effectively the browser will notice that your server isn't even accepting the request (even though its short) and assumes quite rightly, that if the request isn't even read, then the response can't be any good.

Oops, I accidentally ELI5-ed this ... well, I'll leave it as it is.